# Зависимости по умолчанию в Android-проекте

Tags: android-studio, gradle, зависимости

При работе с Android Studio я использую сборку Gradle. Есть ли какой-то способ добавить dependencies по-умолчанию? Например, я постоянно использую библиотеку ButterKnife и ещё несколько. Как перестать постоянно их прописывать? Чтобы при создании проекта они сами добавлялись.

Comment: Сколько у вас проектов с этой библиотекой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Например, вы можете заменить дефолтный шаблон из `Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root\build.gradle.ftl`.

Comment: Это оказалось не совсем то, что мне нужно, но вы задали верное направление) Ответ прилагаю.

Comment: @ИгорьСмирнов моя задача - подтолкнуть людей на собственные поиски. Рад слышать, что поиски увенчались успехом)